# Object 2014-03-17 11:02:08 has no method 'getTimezoneOffset'

Tags: javascript, php, datetime

Got error when getting date from database: Object 2014-03-17 11:02:08 has no method 'getTimezoneOffset'. I am very unsure where the fault come from. Hope that was as clear as it sounded in my head when I wrote it, and thanks for your help!

[image]

Code:

```
<?php

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Failed to connect with database!!!!");
mysql_select_db("chart", $con);

$sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM googlechart");

$rows = array();
//flag is not needed
$flag = true;
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(

 // Labels for your chart, these represent the column titles
    // Note that one column is in "string" format and another one is in "number" format as pie chart only required "numbers" for calculating percentage and string will be used for column title
    array('label' => 'Time',    'type' => 'datetime'),
    array('label' => 'PH',      'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'temperature','type' => 'number'), 
    array('label' => 'Chlorine','type' => 'number'),


    );

    $rows = array();

while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
     $temp = array();
        $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['Time']); 
        $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['PH']);
        $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['temperature']);
        $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['Chlorine']);



        $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Time']);   
        $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);

}

 $table['rows'] = $rows;
 $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
 echo $jsonTable;   

?>


<html>
  <head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);



        var options = {
        /*width: 900, height: 900, */
          title: 'Visualization',
          curveType: 'function', 
           legend: { position: 'bottom' },
           pointSize: 12,
        vAxis: {title: "Values", titleTextStyle: {italic: false}},
        hAxis: {title: "Time", titleTextStyle: {italic: false}},
        explorer: { 
                actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'], 
                axis: 'vertical'
            }


        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);


      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see `getTimezoneOffset()` in your code

Comment: I dont have it, where do I have to put it in ?

Comment: I figured you were using it to get that error message. Guess not. Must be in the Google code.

Comment: Did you mean your error is occurring inside PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: No, when I run it in the browser: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h04z5twtauv6eee/test.png

Comment: doesn't appear to be a PHP error, otherwise it would look different. So most likely a problem in the JavaScript portion, specifically in the google JavaScript portion, or the use of it.

Comment: I didn't find the problem. Please help!

Comment: Something that is expecting a `Date` object is being handed a string instead.  Somewhere you need `new Date(yourString)`.